# python script is not able to invoke chrome driver on azure

Tags: python, azure, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When I am checking my automation script on azure which is trying to invoke chrome driver, it is giving me below error. Script is in python.

```
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: INFO] step2
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ]   File "seleniumtest.py", line 21, in <module>
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ]     driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\env\\chromeinstaller\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe")
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ]   File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ]     self.service.start()
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ]   File "D:\home\site\wwwroot\env\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ]     stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ]   File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ]     errread, errwrite)
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ]   File "D:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ]     startupinfo)
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: ERR ] WindowsError: [Error 14001] The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: SYS INFO] Status changed to Failed
[05/19/2017 11:36:19 > cbe7c6: SYS ERR ] Job failed due to exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your error information, per my experience, I think you were using Azure App Services to try to drive a chrome you uploaded via webdriver to load some dynamic web content to extract something.

However, accoring to [the restrictions of Azure Web App sandbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions), you could not use anything which will call GDI system on Azure WebApp. About the Windows Error, you can refer to [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-pictures/error-the-application-has-failed-to-start-because/df019c0d-746e-42d0-ad68-465e18e3f3ef) to know more details.

As a workaround way, my suggestion is that you can try to run your code on Azure VM. Or per my guess based on the tags for this thread, I think you just might want to do some web unit test via webdriver with chromedriver, please see [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Google Chrome File location or on your desktop shortcut icon -> Right-click -> Properties -> Open File Location.

You will see two applications of chrome: chrome.exe and chrome_new.exe. Run the chrome_new.exe and it will delete and replace the previous chrome.exe.

After that, you will now be able to start and use Google Chrome again.